# NGINX returns 404 on images

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have a server block on nginx that looks like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.mysimplesite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5676;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    location /public/ {
        root /home/me/veryveryverylongpath/public;
    }
}
```

When I try to go to `sub.mysimplesite.com/public/imagename` it returns `404`, any help? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root)

```
location /public/ {
    root /home/me/veryveryverylongpath/public;
}
```

Requests for `/public/img.png` would be looked for at `/home/me/veryveryverylongpath/public/public/img.png`

So you can use the [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directive.

```
location /public/ {
    alias /home/me/veryveryverylongpath/public/;
}
```

on request of `/public/img.png`, the file at `/home/me/veryveryverylongpath/public/img.png` will be sent.

Comment: When location matches the last part of the directive’s value:

location /images/ {
    alias /data/w3/images/;
}
it is better to use the root directive instead:

location /images/ {
    root /data/w3;
}

maybe this is the case, also i tried alias, and tried changing the location and still falls to 404

Comment: can it be permissions issue?

Comment: If you are going to use the root directive then you need to remove `/public/` from your root path. `nginx` would return a 403 for a permissions issue.

Comment: Is it being sent to your proxy?

Comment: nope, don't think so, 
i'm doing this now , but still 404 location /served/ {
                alias /home/joseph/projects/elblo2-beta/elblo2/elblo2-backend/elblo2/public;
        }
... my proxy is for teh APIs only

Comment: i have a proxy for public folder, but since  I changed the location to `served`, i think it's not an issue now

Comment: there was a trailing / that fixed it